# How add product to cart woocomerce by hook?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook, hook-woocommerce

I'm trying to implement the following solution:

```
add_action('woocommerce_calculate_totals' , 'buy3');
function buy3(WC_Cart $cart){
global $woocommerce;
$woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart(6373,1,7444);
}
```

but the problem after execute the code  all quantity the product add To cart not one quantity

Comment: if not one, how many?

Comment: all stock available in product
http://imgur.com/a/kWRZD

Comment: it's a recursive loop :) why do you want to add after calculating total ? can you describe the scenario/ business logic ?

Comment: need to calculates attribute if attribute >20 add one product same attribute gift [simple need buy 1 get 1 free ]

Answer (score 0):

[image: Sold Individually]

Can you Confirm that Sold individually is un-checked? Because WooCommere `add_to_cart()` Force the quantity to 1 if sold individually and it also check for existing item in cart

Also Parameters for `add_to_cart()` function are as below :

```
global $woocommerce;
$woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart($product_id,$quantity,$variation_id, $variation,$cart_item_data);
```

According to the code you provided, you have supplied `quantity = 1`;

Comment: ok but the problem here i can't add more 1 after enable Sold individually

Comment: You don't have to enable Sold individually. Sold individually will let users buy only one quantity per order. Leave Sold individually un-checked if you want to add more than one quantity of that product in cart

Comment: ok the option is un-ckecked 
but the same problem is function not add one imgur.com/a/kWRZD

Comment: Because you already have 306 product in cart. Check your cart again. 1 row for 1 qty and 2nd row for 305 qty

Comment: I'm add  first product from website Manual & hook add 305 loop this is problem why the `woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart` work loop

Comment: Why don't you remove one qty from cart and try the code again? Also make sure the `add_action('woocommerce_calculate_totals' , 'buy3');` action is not in any loop

Comment: with return same problem http://imgur.com/S7ikL3h
without return http://imgur.com/a/TPKGD

Comment: `function buy3()` is being called multiple times. You need to change your logic or check existing cart data, if cheapest item is already in cart, don't add again